# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ hamachi hostname issue

Tags: raspberry-pi3, hamachi, octoprint

Hi everyone randomly browsing overflow stacks!

I own 2 raspberries (pi 3 B and pi 3 B + models), the worse one running OctoPrint for my 3D printer.

Since **my router and provider doesn't allow me to portforward anything**, I have to use hamachi to be able to access these two devices from outside internet. Both raspberries are connected to same network on my LogMeIn hamachi account and both have custom hostnames...

OctoPi has default hostname - **octopi.local**
Pi 3B+ has custom hostname (added manually) - **vps.local** (changed in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname)

The issue is, that I can access both devices via hostname from local network (vps.local and octopi.local), but I can access **only octopi.local via hamachi!!!**

I can normally access my vps.local raspberry via it's hamachi IPv4 address, only hostname doesn't work.. also, when I ping this hostname, I am able to receive hamachi IPv4 address, so it's really weird...

I am up for any help! Thanks! :D

PS: I am sorry for my bad English... haha